# Is it OK to use the chain of http.HandlerFunc?

Tags: go

Using Go http package for a while, I found a convenient way to split responsibilities of the target (endpoint) of HTTP request, over several chain call of http.HandlerFunc:

```
func HeaderValidator(h func(http.ResponseWriter, *HttpRequest)) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *HttpRequest) {
        ...
        h(w, req)
    }
}
```

So now, the handler looks like:

```
router.HandleFunc("/", handler.Log(handler.HeaderValidator(handler.RequestTimer(handler.TargetHandler))))
```

I guess this is not so good from an efficiency point of view (at least, it requires a stack allocation for a functions call) as well as code readability hurts a bit.

Is there a more graceful and efficient way to do that?

Comment: This is a very common way to handle middleware chains. Some third-party libraries provide "helpers" for this but it ends up with the same result.

Comment: It's common to use the approach outlined in the question.

Comment: You should check this [Link](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware) showing the same with better code readability. Also for much better code readability you can use [Negroni](https://github.com/urfave/negroni) package for handling middlewares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, I have some old Go code that does exactly that.

I have somewhat newer Go code which uses github.com/justinas/alice to manage middleware before passing it on to gorilla/mux.

My current Go code just uses gorilla/mux's now built in middleware handling, `Router.Use()`, which looks a lot cleaner than either of the previous solutions, and doesn't require any *more* third party libraries.